# Setting current controller name to a knockout observable on page load using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have the following `view model` in a separate .JS file:

```
var vm = {

ControllerName:ko.observable(),
getData: function () {

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/'+this.ControllerName+'/GetData',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data:jsonData,
    success: function(data){
       // code to bind the data
    }
  });

} }

$(function () {
ko.applyBindings(C1ViewModel);
C1ViewModel.getVisibleAndInvisibleColumns(); });
```

I have to set the `ControllerName` observable with the current asp.net mvc controller name and use this observable in the `getData` function so that the controller name is always dynamic. Since we cannot execute server side razor code in .JS files I would have to pass the current controller name from my markup file where I can get the current controller name by writing server side razor code.

My question is how can I pass a value from my html to my view model, set it in an observable and use it as a global value throughout my view model? Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do above?

Comment: `this.ControllerName` has to be `this.ControllerName()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use script tags in your markup to declare a JS variable that sets the controller name. You can then access this is your .JS file:

**CSHTML**

```
<script>
    var urlForController = "@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", 
                                 new { httproute = "", 
                                       controller = "ControllerNameHere", 
                                       action = "GetData" })";    
</script>
```

You can add additional logic in this code if the controller name varies on some specific criteria.

**AJAX Call in JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlForController,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data:jsonData,
    success: function(data){
       // code to bind the data
    }
  });
```